# Ordering macro argument execution

Tags: macros, rust

I'm using a library for string interning ([string-cache](https://github.com/servo/string-cache)), that uses macros to efficient create elements (`atom!`). However for simplification here is a similar macro that demonstrates the problem

```
macro_rules! string_intern {
   ("d") => ("Found D");
}
```

say I need to call this macro from another macro and give it a string version of an identifier.

```
macro_rules! print_ident {
    ($id:ident) => (
        string_intern!(stringify!($id));
    );
}
```

However calling this macro

```
fn main() {
    print_ident!(d);
}
```

Fails with error:

```
error: no rules expected the token `stringify`
 --> <anon>:7:24
  |
7 |         string_intern!(stringify!($id));
  |                        ^^^^^^^^^
```

[Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?code=macro_rules!%20string_intern%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%28%22d%22%29%20%3D%3E%20%28%22Found%20D%22%29%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Amacro_rules!%20print_ident%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%28%24id%3Aident%29%20%3D%3E%20%28%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20string_intern!%28stringify!%28%24id%29%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%29%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Afn%20main%28%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20hello%20%3D%20%22%22%3B%0A%20%20%20%20print_ident!%28d%29%3B%0A%7D&version=nightly&backtrace=0)

I know `stringify!` correctly converts to identifier `d` to string `"d"`, because giving it to `println!` works as expected. Is there a way to pass the identifier I want turned into string to `string_intern`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`println!` lets you do this because it uses [`format_args!`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.format_args!.html) under the covers, which is a compiler-provided "intrinsic" that forcibly evaluates its first argument *before* using it.  You cannot do this from a user-defined macro; you'd have to write a compiler plugin (which requires a nightly compiler and no guarantee of stability).

So, yeah; you can't.  Sorry.  The only thing you can do is redefine the macro in such a way that you don't *need* an actual string literal, or change how you invoke it.

Answer (score 1):

Your definition of `string_intern!` is expecting a literal `"d"` and nothing else, but you are passing in these tokens: `stringify`, `!`, ... which why it fails. The definition of `string_intern!` that you want is probably:

```
macro_rules! string_intern {
    ($e:expr) => {
        match $e {
            "d" => "Found D",
            _ => "Not found",
        }
    }
}
```

which can accept any expression that evaluates to a string type.

Comment: It's just a shorthand. Basically, I can't ask of you to download `string-cache` to solve this example, so this is MVP for this problem.

Comment: @DanielFath Ah! I guess I didn't understand your intention correctly... So you absolutely wanted compile-time matching...